# Product id of last inserted item in codeigniter shopping cart

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, cart

I am developing a shopping cart using codeigniter cart and ajax. When I add a product to cart a modal popup will show the details of product added. my issue is to get the product id of last inserted item.

> Ajax code

```
$(".add_to_cart").click(function(event) {

  var id=$(this).data('id'); 

  var qty=$("#item_"+id).val();

  $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo base_url("ajax_controller/add_to_cart/'+id+'/'+qty+'")?>',
            data: { id:id }, 
            success:function(response){
            $("#total_items").html(response);
            /*$(".view_cart").click();*/
             $(".product_add").click();
     }
  });/* Aajx */

});/* Add to cart clicked */

$(".product_add").click(function(event) {

 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo site_url("ajax_controller1/product_add")?>',
            data: { id:'1' }, 
            success:function(response){
              $("#cart_container").html(response);
                $("#myModal_cart").modal('show');
     }
  });/* Aajx */



});
```

```html
<li style=""><a href="javascript:void(0);"  class="product_add" >Last Item</a></li>
```

> And My ajax controller

```html
public function add_to_cart($pid,$qty)
    {
               $this->load->library('cart');

        $this->load->model('product_model');
        $query=$this->product_model->get_product($pid);

        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $name=$row->product_name;
            $price=$row->price;
            $img=$row->img_name;
        }


            $data = array(
               'id'      => $pid,
               'qty'     => $qty,
               'price'   => $price,
               'name'    => $name,
               'options' => array('Status' => 'New')
            );

            $this->cart->insert($data);
            $lid = $this->db->insert_id();

            echo count($this->cart->contents());
    }
  public function product_add()
    {
  /*in this controler i need to get id of last inserted product*/
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function product_add()  
 {  
     $id=$this->db->insert_id(); //its return last insert item on table   
     echo $id;  
     exit();  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried

```
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
```